# PHP header refresh warning

Tags: php, header, refresh

I have this code :

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "".$_SESSION['eventnum']."";
$urlRefresh = "testremot.php";
header("Refresh: 5; URL=\"" . $urlRefresh . "\"");
?>
```

but the header doesn't work and this warning appear when I try to run this code:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\remot\testremot.php:3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\remot\testremot.php on line 5**

Can you please help me?

Comment: duplicate of a gazilion other questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+headers+already+sent

Comment: is there anything before <?php tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lets see what you have in `line 3`:

```
echo "".$_SESSION['eventnum']."";
```

Obviously you are generating output (`echo`) in this line and this line comes before you call `header`.
Move it below `header`:

```
session_start();
$urlRefresh = "testremot.php";
header("Refresh: 5; URL=\"" . $urlRefresh . "\"");
echo "".$_SESSION['eventnum']."";
```

---

But note (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Refresh_Meta_tag_and_HTTP_refresh_header)):

> The W3C's [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (7.4)](http://www.w3.org/TR/WAI-WEBCONTENT/#tech-no-periodic-refresh) discourage the creation of auto-refreshing pages, since most web browsers do not allow the user to disable or control the refresh rate.

Answer (score 2):

You can not echo anything before issuing a header. If you MUST, then the only solution is to do output buffering.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $urlRefresh = "testremot.php";
  header("Refresh: 5; URL=\"" . $urlRefresh . "\"");
  echo "".$_SESSION['eventnum']."";
?>
```

headers must be set before you display anything at all, there are a lot of questions like this around...

Comment: thank you it works

I know that I have not print anything befor header but i thought this strict only for HTML codes, not php echo :)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `Refresh` header. And do not show anything for 5 seconds. That's usability fault.
Make a page vieweventnum.php and use a Location header to bring user there

Answer (score 0):

basma, remove any whitespace before `<?php` or any string before php tag. this code should work properly if there are no space or other character before opening `<?php`

Comment: the code run successfully in my server if there are nothing before php. maybe there were something she missing to paste here at line 3. i mean actual code.